# Layout position change with animation in android

Tags: android, animation, layoutparams, window-managers

In my application I have made chathead

I can change position of this chathead using

```
windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
```

But it does not change position with animation.

How can I get animation on move

I have tried following but it does not work.

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, params.x, 0, params.y);
anim.setDuration(1000);
chatHead.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the params.x and params.y value is correct or not?

Comment: Yes it is correct and working with `updateViewLayout`

Answer (score 0):

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new new TranslateAnimation( 0, params.x, 0, params.y);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
                {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)chatHead.getLayoutParams();

                    **//set margin according to your calculation**

                    params.topMargin = mTopMargin;
                    params.leftMargin = 0;
                    chatHead.setLayoutParams(params);

            });

            chatHead.startAnimation(anim);
        }
```

or

use anim.setFillAfter(true);